# civicrm mosaico optout token goes to unsubscribe page

Tags: civimail, mosaico, opt-out

Using Mosaico V2

This token  - {action.optOutUrl}

resolves to this:

https://nbts1.nubay.net/civicrm/mailing/optout?reset=1&jid=112&qid=48&h=e3c048a15c39a655

which goes to this page
[image]

Seems like a bug.  Is it?

Comment: which version of mosaico 2.0 - i see several

Comment: 2.0-beta3.1512698300

Comment: Works if you put a link with same optout token in text panel.    Top panel is problem as it doesn't support full set of text options

Comment: When I click on the link mentioned in the description, it correctly navigates to the opt-out page. Do you mean the opt-out token doesn't resolve to the pasted link?

Comment: interesting - when I click on the same link in the email message itself it goes to the unsubscribe page.   Is it possible that when there is an error in processing the  link, civi defaults to unsubscribe rather than opt-out link?

Comment: Is it possible that an error processing link causes civi to default to the unsubcribe page rather than optout page?  Although it successfully shows the correct email address.   I can't attach image but have checked and the link in the email is the same as posted above but it definitely goes to unsubscribe setting

Comment: Regardless, it would be helpful if the "link" href option existed in top panel page so that tokens such as optout can be correctly inserted in that location